# C# disable aero snap for WPF window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [disable Aero Snap (wpf)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470685/disable-aero-snap-wpf)

I have an application in C# WPF. I want the main window to have fixed size. To achieve this, I have set the height and max height, width and max width, to the same values. Everything looks fine, but I want also to disable Aero snap effect for this window only.

1. The solution to disable Aero snap from Windows Registry or Control Panel is excluded.
2. Setting the ResizeMode of the window to "NoResize" is also excluded, because in this way the window border dissapear too.

Do you have any working solution for this problem in C# ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470685/disable-aero-snap-wpf

Answer (score 3):

You can try to change the `ResizeMode` to `NoResize` only temporarily as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6657804/1374267).

Otherwise you can try [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10458343/1374267) also but I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: None of these work actually. I have tried them before without success. One of them does not work at all and the other removes the window border when the drag of the window is done and leaves the window without border.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found a solution, after 2 days of searching all over the Internet.

http://programminghacks.net/2009/10/19/download-snapping-sticky-magnetic-windows-for-wpf

Unfortunately it does not work with borderless windows.