# How Can I Move The Window Like I Want With WinApi

Tags: c#, winapi, move, message

When I try to drag my window with this the window jumps and flickers around:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_MOVE)
    {
        int x = (m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff);
        int y = ((m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16) & 0xffff);

        if (x < 500)
            Location = new Point(0, y);
        else
            base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
    else
        base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

- must stop jumping
- `WM_MOVE`, `WM_MOVING`, `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` or other move event must continue firing while dragging the window because I want every new position to be checked.
- another problem is `Location = new Point(0, y);` fires another move event (this one should be ignored)

**Please help!**

Comment: Are you simply trying to prevent moving the window by dragging?  Where does the window start (are you setting 0,0 at inception)?

Comment: You are forgetting about the WM_MOVING message.  Why this needs to be "winapi" is very unclear, the LocationChanged event works well enough.

Comment: Sounds to me like you should be using [WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632653(v=vs.85).aspx).  You can change the WINDOWPOS structure to modify the window position and/or size.  Use Marshal.PtrToStructure() to get it out, and Marshal.StructureToPtr() to put it back; very similar to what I did [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16932384/2330053) with WM_GETMINMAXINFO.

Comment: @Idle_Mind If I modify the windowpos structure that wont fire a move/poschanging event right ? Can you make an answer and help out how to do so (earn points) ?

Comment: The initial move and "snap" will fire a Move() event, but afterwards none would be generated...it would just stick to the spot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of using WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING and modifying the WINDOWPOS structure:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public struct WINDOWPOS
    {
        public IntPtr hwnd;
        public IntPtr hwndInsertAfter;
        public int x;
        public int y;
        public int cx;
        public int cy;
        public uint flags;
    }

    public const int WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING = 0x46;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING:
                WINDOWPOS wp = (WINDOWPOS)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(WINDOWPOS));
                if (true) // ... if somecondition ...
                {
                    // modify the location with x,y:
                    wp.x = 0;
                    wp.y = 0;
                }
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StructureToPtr(wp, m.LParam, true);
                break;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
{
    const Int32 WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
    const Int32 SC_MOVE = 0xF010;

    switch (message.Msg)
    {
        case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
            Int32 command = message.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0;
            if (command == SC_MOVE)
            {
                Left = 0;
                Top = 0;
                return;
            }
            break;
    }

    base.WndProc(ref message);
}
```

Hans Passant suggested the `LocationChanged` event, and it can work quite nicely.  In this example, the window is frozen at `0, 0` until the mouse pointer gets outside of a `500, 500` box:

```
private void Form1_LocationChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MousePosition.X > 500 || MousePosition.Y > 500)
        Location = MousePosition;
    else
        Location = new Point(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: This event doesn't fire often only once when you start to move the window. I don't want it to stay at `(0, 0)` ALL the time but to decide when I let it move or keep it at one location.

Comment: You've provided nothing to suggest such logic.  You must explain that if you'd like it to be part of the answer.

Comment: What is this decision-making process then?  What criteria for move versus relocate versus do nothing?  Put _that_ in the `if` block and set `Left` and `Top` accordingly.  Such as `Left = MousePostion.X` instead of zero.

Comment: Sorry maybe this is a misunderstanding. Note the big edit in the question please.

Comment: The misunderstanding is that we don't know what you want it to do.  You grab the window, start to move it, you make it jump to `0, 0`...then what?  If you don't want it to stay at `0, 0`, then what determines when it _doesn't_ stay put?

Comment: Have you tried a clean form with my `WndProc` above ? Make it `if (true)` and then see what happens!