# How to disable maximizing of a window when the window is moved to the top left corner of the screen?

Tags: c#, wpf, window-resize, maximize

I have a windows which hasResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" and AllowTransparency="true" set.
It works fine until it is moved to the top of the screen when it is then automatically Maximized.

How can stop it maximizing so I can display the screen as a window positioned at the top of the screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you disable Aero Snap in an application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470685/how-do-you-disable-aero-snap-in-an-application)

Comment: This is an OS behavior which you should consider very carefully before overriding it.

Comment: The normal way to turn off windows snapping is in the Ease of Access Center : http://windows.microsoft.com/is-is/windows7/how-do-i-turn-snap-on-or-off

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
private void Window_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.WindowState = System.windows.WindowState.Normal;
}
```

If you have to be specific, check for your location:

```
    if (this.Top == 0)
    {
        this.WindowState = System.windows.WindowState.Normal;
    }
```